# How to fix Seagate backup plus not readable on Mac?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, backup, high-sierra, external-disk

I never had a problem with Seagate backup plus for Mac desktop until now. I connected it, and it keeps saying "disk not readable". I have only used it on one device. I have options to initialize, ignore, and reject. How to fix it? I have MacOS high Sierra version 10.13.4 (17E199)

Comment: @Allan I can't access the external hard drive at all, but it shows up in disk utility as untitled. So even if I can create an image, I don't know how to get my Mac to read it. I have a working WD drive. Is there a way to get my files to my Mac or WD drive without a PC? I don't have a PC

Comment: In the linked dupe, there is advice on data recovery.  I won't lie, it's most likely that your drive has failed and recovery will be very difficult, if not impossible.